# Use Java within Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts

I have a jsp page that looks like the following:

What the intent is, is to get the current environment via a system variable and then generate the correct url for that environment.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="logic" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" %>

<%
String sysEnv = "";
if(System.getProperty("env.name").equals("test")) {
    sysEnv = "test";
} 
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html>
<head>
    <%@ include file="/includes/common.jsp" %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:out value="${requestScope.scriptsLocation}"/>/scripts/general.js"></script>

    <c:if test="${requestScope.isFeed == true}">
        <jsp:include page="/includes/someInclude.jsp"/>
        <script src="http://www.myothersite.com/feed/d/some.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

       var environ = <%=sysEnv%>;

        if(environ == 'test'){
                var theUrl = 'http://mywebsite.com?isFeed=true&env=TEST';
        } else {
        var theUrl = 'http://mywebsite.com?isFeed=true';
        }

       ...

    </script>

...
```

I think I'm supposed to have the tags-logic import to do the looping that I'm trying to achieve in Java, but this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already in a JSP why not just do (roughly) this:

```
<script>
  var url = 'http://mywebsite.com?isFeed=true';
  if ('<%= System.getProperty("env.name") %>' === 'test') {
    url += '&env=TEST';
  }
  // etc.
```

Personally I'd move this logic out of the view and create a request-scoped attribute in a filter, as part of your Struts 1 request processor, etc. since scriptlets are almost always bad. It also gives you the opportunity to set it at runtime.

In addition, the URL generation should *also* likely be moved out of the view layer.